# Would I be able to run Java programs without having the entire kit downloaded?

Tags: java

I have recently started coding in Java.
I was wondering, is it mandatory to have the entire Java kit to run the computer from a different computer? Because, I am not using the resources from the entire API, just a few particular ones.

I wouldn't want to get the entire JDK pack for a single project. Any help would be nice,

Thank you.

Comment: you don't need the JDK to run applications, you only need it to write and compile them. if you only want to run them, the JRE is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop your own Java applications, then yes, you need the entire JDK. However, there are several JDK alternatives available and I believe the SE JDK should be enough for you. You can find it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, you only need JRE (runtime). Hoverwer, to develop program you do need to have JDK.

Comment: I'd put the "only" in quotes, it's still an extra install (and the "official" Oracle one pushing Ask! crapware is just *nasty*).

Answer (score 0):

To run an already completed app in other machines, you just need the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) installed in those machines. You need the JDK (Java Development Kit) for development. The JDK already comes with the JRE.